# Regex to validate string format and structure based on a given set of labels

Tags: regex

I check a string with a Regex for its valid structure and format.

The Regex I use:
`^(?!.+(more|enough|less)+$)(^(?:more|enough|less))[a-z_,]+$`

- The 1st part of the Regex says: do not end with one of the labels and without whitespace.
- The 2nd part of the Regex says: start with one of the labels followed by any characters => and here is the problem I have!
  The rule must be: Start with one of the labels, followed by any characters. Additionally the other labels may appear again, but only once, and they must begin with a ",".

The format and structure of the string can contain a "," as delimiter and follows the rule:

- *[[**more**|**enough**|**less**{topic}][_{aspect}]*
- *[[**more**|**enough**|**less**{topic}][*{aspect}],[[**more**|**enough**|**less**{topic}][*{aspect}]*

Whereby the label **more**, **enough** and **less** may only be contained once in the string.

My Regex works for nearly all combinations, except:

- lesschips,lessfish
- lesschipsmorebier_cold

For testing I use the following combinations:

- morefish
- morefish_fried
- lesschips
- morebier_cold,lesschips,enoughwater
- lesschips,morebier_cold

... and the following invalid combinations:

- more
- morefish => the example ends with a whitespace
- morefish
- moreless
- lessmore
- leschips
- lesschips,lessfish
- lesschipsmorebier_cold
- morebier_cold,lesschips,enough

Answer (score 1):

You can use another negative lookahead to exclude matching one of the same alternatives twice without crossing a comma using a negative lookahead.

And another negative lookahead to not match any of the alternatives twice before crossing a comma.

As you are not matching spaces, you can use `\S` to match any whitspace char instead of `.` which can also match a space.

```
^(?!\S*(?:more|enough|less)$)(?!\S*?(more|enough|less)\S*?\1)(?!\S*?(?:more|enough|less)[^\s,]*?(?:more|enough|less))(?:more|enough|less)[a-z_]*(?:,(?:more|enough|less)[a-z_]*)*$
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!\S*(?:more|enough|less)$)` Do not match the words at the end of string
- `(?!\S*?(more|enough|less)\S*?\1)` Do not match the same words twice in the string
- `(?!\S*?(?:more|enough|less)[^\s,]*?(?:more|enough|less))` Do not match any of the words together in the same part without matching a comma
- `(?:more|enough|less)[a-z_]*` Start the match with any of the alternatives and optional chars a-z or `_`
- `(?:,(?:more|enough|less)[a-z_]*` Optionally repeat matching a comma and again one of the alternatives and optional chars a-z or `_`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mSuQSp/1)